# Blazor not found when using query parameters

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

When i use query Parameters and start to navigate to the url my .Net 8 Blazor Web App shows me not found
Url: https://localhost:7015/qrcode/info?Id=4a6830b2-0e4a-4c46-8cf0-ed01855ee65e&Type=Cylinder&Name=Tobias%20Steinmetz&MFG=Luxfer&Size=12&Snr=13254342&maxBar=200&checkBar=350

Razor Page:

```
@page "/qrcode/info"

@using DPW.Shared.Models.QrCode

<h1>QRCode Daten</h1>

@code {
 [Parameter]
 [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "Id")]
 public string Id { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "Type")]
public string Type { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "MFG")]
public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "Snr")]
public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "Size")]
public decimal Size { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "maxBar")]
public int MaxPressure { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "checkBar")]
public int CheckPressure { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which template options did you select?  Render mode and interactivity?

Comment: I've just posted your code into a new project and it works.  Either your site url is wrong or there's more that you aren't showing in your question.